# (Java) I can't figure out how to populate an array with a counter controlled loop which is required

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random, shuffle

I have to:
Create an array that models a deck of cards. For example, “1_of_diamonds” represents the ace of
diamonds, “2_of_diamonds” represents the 2 of diamonds, up to “13_of_diamonds”, which
represents the King of diamonds. The suits clubs, hearts and spades are represented in a similar
manner. All these elements should be in a single array. The array should be populated using a
counter controlled loop. Output the contents of the array to the screen.
Shuffle the deck.

I have the code to shuffle it working but I do not know how to populate the array with a counter controlled loop.

//this is my code

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Cards{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

} //end main

public String[] shuffle(String[] deck) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = deck.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        // Simple swap
        String a = deck[index];
        deck[index] = deck[i];
        deck[i] = a;
    }
    return deck;

}
}// end class
```

Comment: Share the complete code. Looks like you just have copied the shuffle method from somewhere.

Comment: We did the code for the shuffle method in class, I know I need it for this so I just copied it in. Sorry if this isn't much to go on, im just pretty new to java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

populate method below may help.

```
public static String[] populate(){
    String[] cards=new String[52];
    String[] types={"hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"};
    int current = 0;
    for(String type:types)
        for(int i = 1; i <= 13 ; i++)
            cards[current++] = i + "_of_" + type;

    return cards;
}
```

Comment: Good. Would you consider accepting the answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

There is the Java8+ way using streams and the older way using loops. I assume you want the older way, but I thought it might be interesting to do both.

```
    // Streams way
    String[] array = Stream.of("spades", "diamonds", "hearts", "clubs")
            .map(suit -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 13).mapToObj(value -> value + "_of_" + suit))
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .toArray(String[]::new);

    // for loops way
    String[] deck = new String[52];

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        String suit;
       switch(i){
           case 0:
               suit = "spades";
               break;
           case 1:
               suit = "diamonds";
               break;
           case 2:
               suit = "hearts";
               break;
           case 3:
           default:
               suit = "clubs";
               break;
       }
       for(int value = 0; value < 13; value++){
           deck[i * 13 + value] = (value + 1) + "_of_" + suit;
       }
    }


    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deck));
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, the for loop bit is what I needed. the other method is really interesting to see to so thank you for sharing!